# Amd Raedon 7950 HD with 3 Displays verry slow

Tags: ati, multiple-monitors

my dream is to play Flightgear on 3 Displays.
Therefore I have the following machine:

Intel® Core™ i5 CPU 760 @ 2.80GHz × 4

8 GB Ram

Amd Raedon 7950 HD

3 Displays each running with 1920x1080

I tried nearly all driver Options (Opensource, Proprietary and currently AMD Beta 12.11)
Drivers seam to be correctly installed.

```
fglrxinfo
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 7900 Series 
OpenGL version string: 4.2.11995 Compatibility Profile Context
```

Glxgears in standart size (As it opens)

```
3717 frames in 5.0 seconds = 743.318 FPS
4033 frames in 5.0 seconds = 806.506 FPS
4137 frames in 5.0 seconds = 827.231 FPS
4266 frames in 5.0 seconds = 853.051 FPS
```

The System is running - but somehow slow alltogether. 
Mouse is hanging from time to time, Desktopswitch takes 20sec etc.

And in Flightgear i get 8 Fps/sec. No different if i open one normalsize Window or the 3 Display setup.

Question:

Is my Hardware not big enough for this setup. (Processor maybe?)
or do you think there is a setup Problem?

Do you need other testoutputs to help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had a 3 headed rig recently.  It ran with reasonable frame-rates, but as always with gaming - switch to a non-compositing (not unity3d) desktop for the best performance if you're running things in wine to ease up the load on your card.

My 5850 belted things out fine, despite having some temperature issues with binary drivers.

1) Use the binary driver
2) Back down to a lighter DE for gaming
3) Turn off visual effects you don't need (like wobblywindows et al)
4) Turn off Zeitgeist and disable all the lenses you can

That last part is probably overkill/a little much,but it may help.  Turn off anything that runs constantly.

Comment: Can i switch the desktop for one user only? In my all day work i like unity3d.

Comment: You can switch it any time you log in.

Comment: Thank you. I go to try lubuntu and then tell you how it worked out :)

Comment: O.K. lubuntu desktop gave me 12 fps. Thats not too much. Do you think a faster processor would help?

Comment: I doubt it.  htop should tell you your resource utilization for ram and cpu.  It doesn't seem like a lot, but you got a 50 percent improvement in the game framerate.  You could adjust your resolution down...